# Detect whenever user opens a foreground app

Tags: android, events, android-service

I am developing an android app. I want to know through an event or any other means in my service, whenever user opens a foreground app. I want to collect my own usage statistics, as I can't find a way to know how many times an app has been used.

Does anyone know of a nice way to do this? Or obtain those statistics, already, if possible?

Comment: do you want it with for your own app or all apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of this is supported by the Android SDK.

Comment: When I query the running apps/tasks using ActivityManager, does it give stats about both forground and background app. For example I could poll frequently to see what all apps are running and then count that as a usage?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google Analytics directly?

http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/

Comment: That would give me analytics only about my own app. Thats not what I am looking for.